# How can I have Composer prefer stable releases, but grab a few select dev releases?

Tags: drupal, composer-php

**What I want to do**

I'm trying to manage Drupal 8 and its modules using Composer. Here's what I want to do:

- Use the most recent stable version of modules/libraries whenever possible, except in a few cases where I explicitly declare otherwise.

(Why?  Because occasionally the stable release of a Drupal module is broken but it's fixed in `dev`, so I need the `dev` version in those cases only until a new release is made.)

Here is an example of my `composer.json`:

```
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21@stable",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3@stable",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0@stable",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3@stable",
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "^3.1@stable",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev",
    "drupal/address": ">=8.1.0-beta2@beta",
    "drupal/advagg": ">=8.2.0-beta2@beta",
  },
  "replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.0"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
```

I want the dev version of Bootstrap (`"drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev"`), but because I have set `prefer-stable: true`, then I get the latest Bootstrap alpha, not the dev release.

If I set `prefer-stable: false`, then all the dependencies get switched to dev versions (Symfony, Twig, and so on).

I [read this article on Composer versioning](http://qpleple.com/understand-composer-versions/), but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

EDIT: Note that this `composer.json` requires the Drupal packagist repository:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
    }
  ],
```

Here is the full `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "drupal/drupal",
  "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "version": "8.0.3",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
    "drupal/drupal-extension": "^3.1",
    "drupal/address": "8.1.0-beta2",
    "drupal/advagg": "8.2.0-beta2",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev"
  },
  "replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.0"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
  },
  "extra": {
    "_readme": [
      "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
      "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php."
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
      "include": [
        "core/composer.json"
      ],
      "recurse": false,
      "replace": false,
      "merge-extra": false
    },
    "patches": {
      "drupal/smtp": {
        "Remove install config" : "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/remove_install-2651434-2.patch"
      }
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the `composer.json` you gave as example is not valid:

- Comma at the last line of a section is not allowed.
- `drupal/bootstrap`, `drupal/address` and `drupal/advagg` can not be found at Packagist.

To achieve the following

> Use the most recent stable version of modules/libraries whenever possible, except in a few cases where I explicitly declare otherwise.

you will just need to set the `"minimum-stability": "stable"` which means only stable versions are fetched. And use the `@dev` flag for the explicitly few cases you mentioned. `prefer-stable` is not needed in this case.

Let's take the following `composer.json` as an example. This will install only stable versions of the listed packages:

```
{
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
        "drupal/drupal-extension": "^3.1",
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

If you now change the first line of the `require` section from

```
"composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
```

to

```
"composer/installers": "^1.0.21@dev",
```

It will install only stable versions of all listed packages except `composer/installers`. Because the `@dev` flag overrides the `"minimum-stability": "stable"` this will download the dev version of only this package.

#### Another minimal example with Drupal Packagist:

```
{
    "require": {
       "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
       "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
       "cweagans/composer-patches": "~1.0",
       "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3",
       "drupal/drupal-extension": "^3.1",
       "drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev"
     },
     "replace": {
       "drupal/core": "~8.0"
     },
     "minimum-stability": "stable",
     "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

I used an empty folder only with the `composer.json` from above and I ran `composer install`. (for your project you could remove the `vendor/` folder completely and remove the `composer.lock` before running `composer install`. Make a backup before!).

It installed the latest dev version of `drupal/bootstrap` as you can see from the console output below:

> ```
> - Installing drupal/bootstrap (dev-8.x-3.x 6a37bf5)
>   Cloning 6a37bf5977c54dde4fe58f40118a8c71ce7e145a
> ```

If you compare the hash `6a37bf5977c54dde4fe58f40118a8c71ce7e145a` from the installed version with the source code at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/log/ you can see that it installed the latest version (At this time [`Issue #2672514 by neardark: update documentation`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/commit/?id=6a37bf5977c54dde4fe58f40118a8c71ce7e145a)).

Comment: Thanks, I should have noted that this `composer.json` requires Drupal Packagist.  I appreciate the example.  Unfortunately, when I add `"drupal/bootstrap": "8.3.*@dev",` with `"minimum-stabilitiy": "stable,` this gives me the beta released in December, not the latest dev release from February.

Comment: I added another minimal example to show that my example code is working and it installs the latest version from 10 hours ago (at this time).

Comment: Let's say I switched to the dev version to get a patch I need but I'd like to  return to a stable version a soon as the current dev version is included in the next stable version.  (Of course I need to avoid downgrading at any point a this would mess the database updates of the module) Does composer handle that ?